# How to write JSX code within Return in React Native?

Tags: mongodb, react-native

Im trying to connect my React Native App to a Remote MongoDB server. Im tring to write JSX Statements within the Return of my app.

```
return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text> {loginStatus}</Text>
                {this.state.currentUserId !== undefined ? logoutButton : loginButton}
                {this.state.name !== undefined ? <Text>{this.state.welcomeText}</Text> : this.state.currentUserId !== undefined ? nameInput : ""}
                {(this.state.name == undefined) && this.state.tempName !== undefined ? confirmNameButton : ""}
            </View>
        )
```

Im supposed to get a Welcome Message set to the state if a name is found. If a user is logged in a logout button is displayed else a login button is displayed.
I keep getting this error:
ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

Comment: you must have to wrap the statements inside a View

Comment: @Nishanth wrap your `nameInput ` within a `Text` component

Comment: Wrapping nameInput within a Text component worked. Thanks!